# update query to increment the existing value

Tags: pdo, prepared-statement, isset

Okay so I've been working my tail off trying to figure this out. I think I am getting closer but not close enough. The code below works, however, played only iterates once no matter how many times I wager. So within the database field for played; it always shows the number 1. Each wager sends the JSON to this page, so the idea is for played to continue to climb, 1,2,3,4,5,6... and post every time. I have no problems with the money, it posts to the database the correct variable every time.

```
<?php 
session_start();
if(empty($_SESSION['userid']))
{
    header("Location: ../login/index.php");
}
include('../../login/database.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
 $money = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
 $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
try {
$db = DB();

//$results = $db->query("SELECT played FROM usersystem WHERE userid=:userid");
$stm = $db->prepare("SELECT played FROM usersystem WHERE userid=:userid");
$results = $stm->fetch();



$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE usersystem SET money=:money, played=:played+1 WHERE userid=:userid");
$stmt->bindValue(':money', $money, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->bindValue(':userid', $userid, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->bindValue(':played', $results, PDO::PARAM_INT);
$stmt->execute();

}
catch(PDOException $e)
{
    $db = null;  
    echo $e->getMessage();  
}
}

echo $_POST['package']; 
?>
```

What would allow my math played=:played+1 to work? Do I have to do anything with the variable using isset?

Now I know why I waited so long to focus on php and json, it's quite involved.

Comment: remove a colon from played

Comment: I used a different solution. I fetch POSTed json_decode and used this new value string and a select fetchcolumn to get a new sum and then updated.